# ssh command history and "autocomplete"

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I need to work with ubuntu server remotely using ssh. I have only basic knowledge about linux administration, so it is difficult to work from shell. But any way...
When I connected as root via ssh "autocomplete" for commands and folders using Tab and storing of command history works fine.

I created separate user account for me:

```
sudo useradd andrew
sudo adduser andrew sudo 
sudo passwd andrew
```

after login as andrew server told me, that home directory for "andrew" doesn't exsist, so

```
sudo mkdir /home/andrew
sudo chown andrew:andrew /home/andrew
```

but neither "autocomplete" for commands and folders nor command history doesn't work for this user

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Use `adduser andrew` and not `useradd andrew`. (You'll see in the man page that `useradd` is a low-level utility).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your answer [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163802/backspace-tab-del-and-arrow-keys-not-working-in-terminal-using-ssh/208275)

> Mateng is close in that I think you're probably running Bourne Shell.
>   But you shouldn't be editing your /etc/passwd file directly. Try using
>   the chsh command instead:
>
> **chsh -s /bin/bash** The -s flag will make the new shell (Bash in this
>   case) your login shell, going forward.